# How to generate a noise like Pioneers white noise?

Tags: audio

I am making a music app and I want to put a noise generator in it. The problem is the usual white, pink noise is just too boring and not useful for the user. Pioneer mixers has an amazing noise generator. [Check it here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlZfXxQTy6A)

I want to generate something like this but obviously I have no idea how could such noise can be generated. I am new to DSP and all I need to know is what could be the magic behind this noise? Is it a High pass filtered white noise with some reverb? I need to get some guesses on the formula for this noise and I will do the research and implement it.

More discussion here:
[Generate Smooth Brown Noise Mathematically](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75507/generate-smooth-brown-noise-mathematically/75510?noredirect=1#comment160404_75510)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cool" stuff that you hear has almost nothing to do with the noise itself, but it's all in the post-processing: They use aggressive time variant low-pass and band-pass filtering, manual gain modulation and reverb/echo effects.

Any old pink noise will do just fine for this purpose.

"White noise" is an application specific misnomer. Almost no one uses actual white noise in audio, since it sounds really bad. Mostly it's pink noise or sometimes even brown noise.

Comment: Beyond the color of the noise source, to my ears it sounds like the ‘color’ knob is a band-pass filter with an adjustable cutoff frequency.  Speculating though.

Answer (score 1):

White noise has an unambiguous definition: it's uncorrelated noise. So, anything called white noise was most definitely not high-pass filtered or spectrally shaped specifically: it's got a flat spectrum, by definition. That should sound relatively boring to the human listener: that's inherent to the spectrum.

You've got freedom in determining the amplitude distribution, though. Most commonly, white noise is Gaussian in amplitude - but it doesn't have to be. The thing mathematically required is a zero-mean distribution (otherwise, it couldn't be uncorrelated) and an amount of randomness; the fact you're generating it digitally implies it's variance-limited.

Maybe experiment with noise that only takes two negative and two positive values; maybe with uniform or with two-sided exponentially distributed noise. If you've got a good measurement system, you'll notice white noise that's not very smoothly, low >2nd moment distributed will tend to put your speakers to the test for nonlinearities and that will then un-whiten your spectrum, but that might actually be the effect you're looking for.

Comment: I don’t agree that “the only thing required mathematically is a zero mean distribution” and I am open to debating those details - what is also required is each sample to be independent, the dependency from sample to sample is what adds “color”. This seems to be additionally mathematical criteria that is very important to the definition. I’ll remove my polite down-vote once this is resolved.

Comment: In this context this is just a misnomer. The OP actually means "filtered pink noise". Real white noise sounds quite bad.

Comment: @DanBoschen thanks for the polite down vote! Let me try to resolve this, which might require understanding on my side:

Comment: So, whiteness isn't trivial to define, seeing that we disagree: I'm only requiring uncorrelatedness of samples, which means $E(X(t_1)X(t_2))=0$.  I'll agree, independence + zero-mean is sufficient (if both times are independent but the distribution's not zero mean, the expectation of their product isn't zero, and thus our spectrum would get a DC peak). But is independence necessary? Far as I can tell: no. For example: take $X_i$, hack it into non-overlapping pieces of three samples. Let all samples have the same discrete two-point uniform distribution $P(X_I=-1)=P(X_I=+1)=1/2$...

Comment: Let all consecutive $X_i$ be pairwise independent by the following rule of construction: if $i=0,1\mod3$, generate iid RV $X_i\in\{-1,+1\}$. If $i=2\mod3$, set $X_I=X_{i-1}\cdot X_{i-2}$. Clearly, the third value in each of these three-segments very much depends on the previous two, but the expectation of products of any two different samples, and thus the expectation stays zero. That's white noise in my understanding!

Comment: But: I actually don't know if my correlation-based definition is sufficient for whiteness in practice. Guess it is for some types of noise; if I can show noise is *jointly* Gaussian (not just sample-wise), then independence and uncorrelatedness are the same. And EEs do like to model their noise as Gaussian.

Comment: Not sure if we actually disagree or if you just left out important additional information. I think the only mathematical requirement to be white would be that the power spectral density is constant, which results in the signal to be zero mean rather than zero mean causing it to be white. Every frequency like DC would also be zero (the mean as DC is not really any different from any other frequency). But you’re right independence is not necessary for that; I am always thinking of random variables which if independent would be white but to your point if we filter “white noise”....

Comment: .... (which itself has all samples as independent and uncorrelated) with a linear phase filter, the samples would have dependence but the spectrum would still be “white”. So I think now the right answer is simply a constant PSD is the only mathematical requirement to be white.

Comment: And to be “white noise” implies that in addition to the constant PSD, the samples are all uncorrelated to each other.

Comment: @mmmm  And with the benefit of your good comments I am no longer confident in the anchor on “dependence” vs “uncorrelated” (I know being uncorrelated implies the sample will all be independent but am no longer confident the reverse is true). My objection was saying zero mean is the only requirement so think the answer is improved by saying “the only mathematical requirement to be white noise is a constant PSD and that all samples be uncorrelated from each other”.

Comment: Interesting though that a signal that has all samples uncorrelated from each other will always have a constant PSD and therefore be white- but we can have a white noise constant PSD signal where the samples have an interdependence as given by passing a white noise signal with all samples independent through a linear phase filter.

Comment: I've now been looking into different definitions, and it gets.. sub-canonical pretty quickly. Oppenheimer/Schafer's DTSP 2nd ed defines white noise simply as having constant PSD, indeed, which requires it to be WSS, if I'm not mistaken. Lapidoth's Foundation in Digital Communication defines the same, but always states band-limitation, which precludes the Dirac ACF I demand. Belanger's Digital Processing Of Signals 2nd ed defines it as having a $P\delta$ ACF. So, I think we can always find a set of authors who'd say we're both wrong!

Comment: @mmmm Yes, "Band-limited white noise" is yet another process. And indeed white noise would have a Dirac ACF, if it is truly white with no band-limitation; which shows directly that every sample is uncorrelated to every other sample. I don't think there is any conflict there in that these are properties of white noise. But I would argue the Oppenhiemer/Shafer's definition is not sufficient, given what we discussed. (Sufficient certainly to be white but not to be "noise"). White noise always has a constant PSD, but a constant PSD is not always white noise.

Comment: But if you change your sentence "Only thing mathematically required is a zero-mean distribution (otherwise, it couldn't be uncorrelated)" I will remove my down-vote-- I don't see any disagreement between us from your comments. Just want your answer to best for others, and thanks for humoring the discussion!