# Amplify filtered smooth brown noise to range [-1.0f, +1.0f]

Tags: audio

I am trying to make a "noise generator" like Pioneer [example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlZfXxQTy6A). I am using a smoothed brown noise and passing it to a bandpass filter to achieve this noise in C++.

For [smooth brown noise.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-teK_6JX9gc) I used Hilmars suggestion here. According to [Hilmars answer here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/75510/56906)

I used []=[−1]+⋅(2∗()−1) and passed the resulting signal to a highpass with fc of 20hz and to a lowpass with fc of 40hz.

Here is my C++ code:

```
void BrownNoiseGenerator::tick(float &sample){
    // []=[−1]+⋅(2∗()−1) is below here
    sample = storageSample + 1.0f * distribution(generator); 
    // distribution is std::uniform_real_distribution<float>, generates values between -1.0f, +1.0f
    // i am taking c as 1

    highPass.tickMono(sample); // pass to HPF of 20hz
    lowPass.tickMono(sample); // pass to HPF of 40hz

    storageSample = sample; // this is x[N - 1], initially 0 for the first tick

    // sampleDummy *= 24; // this is explained later in the question

    bandPass.tickMono(sample); // pass to BPF to achieve the "cool" pioneer sound 
}
```

Just to be clear, I am not asking help for my code, I have given the code to make it easy for you to understand my approach.

After aggressive filtering the sample signal value becomes very little like 0.001 and its not audible. What I did is, I amplified the signal with a random value I found by trying to make sure the signals absolute value is greater than 0.1 so that the user can hear the noise. The end result is very good. It sounds similar to Pioneers noise generator. However, since I amplify the signal randomly sometimes I get values absolute over 1.0f which causes distortions and also the range seems to be between 0 to 2.4f and just randomly changes.

My question is how can I ensure that I can amplify this generated signal to an audible level while not messing/distorting its "sound".

Attempt taking Hilmars feedback:

```
    sample = distribution(generator);

    highPass.tickMono(sample);
    lowPass.tickMono(sample);

    if (fabsf(sample) > xMax) {
        xMax = 1.2f * fabsf(sample);
        currentGain = 1 / xMax;
    }

    sample *= currentGain;

    bandPass.tickMono(sample);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code feels wrong.  You use an integrator AND a lowpass, so you get -12dB/octave instead of -6 dB. I would recommend to use `x[n] = 2*rand()-1` and ditch the `+c*x[n-1]` part. That will partially take care of your gain problem.

The gain scaling can be done dynamically using something like this

```
static float xMax = 0, currentGain = 1;
// generate new sample by whatever method
if (fabsf(sample) > xMax) {
  xMax = 1.2f*fabsf(sample);
  currentGain = 1/xMax;
}
sample *= currentGain;
```

This will jitter a bit in the beginning but quickly converge to a stable output that's bounded between +- 0.85 or there abouts. Once you keep this running for a few seconds the value of "currentGain" will be highly stable and you can just hardcode it to remove the startup artifact.

Comment: your method seems reasonable but there is a big problem i am facing, in my code i process the input through filters as you see and idk why but for several seconds filtering gives me high values like 0.85 and it gets smaller and converges fast, if i use your method in those high value stages currentGain is captured very high and it just makes the overall volume very low as things diverge currentGain stays high, i tried several things but none helped me. idk if my low and highpass are broken (which i do not think because i use them individually)

Comment: also i noticed that -12dB/octave sounds more good to ear because it removes the TV static alike noise that is generated at high frequencies which are highly present on white noise, thats why i would like to keep this, I could even maybe have a sharper decrease as it sounds more smooth to the ear

Comment: also added my code to the question for further clarification, also your approach 100% works if i remove the highpass and lowpass but i think then my signal becomes a white noise, i can confirm it as its "tv static" is highly audible

Comment: i used your code and basically waited 5 seconds before activating my noise generator. all seems to work fine, i really appreciate the help, i suck at dsp, thank you for mentoring!